# boost:asio and dlclose() - core dump (illegal instruction)

Tags: boost, boost-asio, aix, coredump

I have application.so on Aix 5.3 and gcc 4.2.4. Application.so uses boost:asio. There is example.c which does dlopen and dlclose for application.so. However, when example.c exits - I get a core dump. Pl note that all operations are performed successfully.

If I comment out boost related code in application.so and still link boost_system.so while building application.so, I still get core dump on exit of example.c . However, if I do not link boost_system.so while building application.so, I do not get any core dump on exit of example.c.

I have tried boost_1_40, boost_1_42 , boost_1_45 and gcc 4.2.0. Has anyone seen this issue before. If yes, any help would be very much appreciated.

```
{
hLib = dlopen(libPath, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
fprintf(stderr, "Before dlclose");
dlclose(hLib);
}
```

Above segment is where the problem occurs. As soon as, example.c exits, I get core dump.

EDIT

When building application.so with boost-system, I am getting following warnings:-

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error>::~error_info_injector`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >::~clone_impl()`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >::~clone_impl()`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >::clone() const`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >::rethrow() const`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error>::~error_info_injector::system_error> >::~clone_impl()`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system:`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .non-virtual thunk to boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >::~clone_impl()`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .global destructors keyed to ras_arg_t`

`ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .global constructors keyed to ras_arg_t`

I am assuming that these duplicate destructors are not getting invoked during dlclose, but during exit - by which time library is unloaded.

Comment: I have not seen this behavior on Linux. Can you post some sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Sam. No I see this on AIX and not on Linux. I have posted isolated block that causes the issue.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example code of `application.so` showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using boost, but am using AIX 5.3-5, and gcc 4.2.0, and experienced a core dump and the

```
"ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .global constructors keyed to ras_arg_t"
```

linkage warning.

The answer to my problem was to add the word `typedef` before the `ras_arg` struct definition in `/usr/include/sys/ras.h`

This is similar to the `thread_credentials` case described here: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=119546